# Python: What is the best approach to find and replace attribute values for an XML tag type?

Tags: python, xml, regex

For some attributes, I wish to validate the values and replace some of them with more succinct ones.

```
<data source="file:\\c:\main\data.txt"/>
```

Replaced by:

```
<data source="c:\main\data.txt"/>
```

Comment: I suggest [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `BeautifulSoup`, you can use it to parse and modify a xml file:

```
>>> s=r'''<data source="file:\\c:\main\data.txt"/>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> t = soup.find("data")
>>> t['source']
'file:\\\\c:\\main\\data.txt'
>>> t['source'][7:]
'c:\\main\\data.txt'
>>> t['source'] = t['source'][7:]
>>> print str(soup)
<html><body><data source="c:\main\data.txt"></data></body></html>
```